# How to fix bad boot resolution in Kubuntu

Tags: 14.04, boot, kubuntu, kde, display-resolution

I have a fresh install of Kubuntu (no updates, no configuration beyond installer questions) connected via HDMI to a 4k TV.  When I boot, I get the bios screen, then it goes black and I don't see anything further.

I'm confident its booting because I am able to log in with `nomodeset` some of the time (I can't seem to reliably get to the grub editor screen) and it does run like that, but then I get no screen resolution options.

I'm fairly new to Linux, so how can I fix this?  My screen is entirely capable of running 720 or 1080 resolution, how can I make it boot at a safe resolution every time?

Answer (score 0):

The black screen problem is normally caused by some update that didn’t install properly and left the graphical desktop environment in a broken state.

The fix this, open a text console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and then logging in in text mode. Once you are in, issue these commands to complete the upgrade successfully:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo reboot.
```

Ubuntu restarts, and then you can log in again normally.

If issues still exists, please let us know.

Comment: No joy here.  I wasn't really expecting this to help as its a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would try hooking it up to a monitor via VGA before using HDMI as HDMI requires specific resolutions for HD output and you don't seem to be getting to the login screen to change it further. Also, GRUB is able to set the resolution during startup, so if you believe it is a resolution issue, you can try setting it from GRUB.

Im summarizing what was written here: [Change boot screen resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127851/change-boot-screen-resolution)

1) login to bash shell as root

2) `nano /etc/default/grub`

3) There is a line that has: GRUB_GFXMODE={resolution}, change the resolution to the desired resolution here. Control+X to exit and type s to save.

4) To keep this resolution, you have to edit `/etc/grub.d/00_header`. Edit this file with Nano, under the line that has: `set gfxmode=${GRUB_GFXMODE}`, write: `set gfxpayload=keep`. Save file as before.

5) Run `update-grub` command

Comment: This is not an answer I am afraid.  You give no instructions on setting those **specific resolutions for HD output** or on **setting it from GRUB**, especially when the guy is stating that they're fairly new to Linux.

Comment: Well, excuse me. I was going to see if this was the solution that he wanted, and proceed from there.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean.  I was following the same pattern when I first joined askubuntu.  It's just the way askubuntu works.  I didn't mean to be offensive or something.  The forum is just following a different pattern.  Answers contain solutions, everything else should be a comment.  That's all.  ;-)

Comment: @MortyV -Actually, I think i understand this, and will try this evening.  I'm a full stack programmer (Microsoft), so not new to CLI or config files.  My issue with Linux is that everything is in a config file that can be edited easily, if only I could find WHICH config file and know exactly WHAT change to make.  :-)

Comment: @MortyV -Also, whats the actual trick to getting the GRUB options when booting?  I seem to stumble on it, but not sure what key is actually doing it.

Comment: I believe it's the shift key

Comment: Not sure what to do next, this didn't work...

Comment: You got through the process I mentioned? What menus are you able to reach? Grub, bash, recovery options, etc.

Comment: I was able to do this entire process, connected another monitor VGA, logged in, went to console and edited both grub files, then updated grub, restarted and unplugged the VGA monitor.  TV showed no change, still goes black after bios.  I was also able to get into Grub editor once, but it doesn't seem to be working on Shift key for me.  I've been to recovery options plenty of times, but config files seem to be read-only from there.

Comment: are you using a laptop or a desktop? On my desktop, for example, there are two outputs from the graphics card and I can have two displays running at once. If that is your scenario, you can open up system settings from the Ubuntu file explorer (it's on the top left), and go to Displays. from there, you can click detect displays, and see if your monitor is being detected, or change the resolution.

Comment: When I get in and set that from the GUI, I still get black screen on boot.  Its like the settings don't save or are getting overridden by some automatic detection code.  Its a stand-alone computer with HDMI and VGA output (not a laptop).

Comment: If found this at http://askubuntu.com/questions/320828/how-to-have-launcher-on-non-primary-screen: Assuming your primary screen is the one you don't want fullscreen apps to run on, do:

    Set your launcher to be on your other screen (not on both), from the Display menu configuration. This will make your primary screen to be the one you want it to be.
    Next, after applying changes set your launcher to be on both screens, then, you'll keep the screen you want as primary one, but you'll be able to use the launcher from the other one.

Comment: this might also be helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/42353/how-to-configure-launcher-placement-in-multi-monitor-setup. Considering there are many things here that could be not working, it's a little hard to diagnose the issues your having. I think if you play around with it a little bit, you should be able to get it working. If nothing else, you'll learn a little bit about Ubuntu.

Comment: @MortyV - I completely understand the difficulty, I will check out these links and try your suggestions further.  I gave you the bounty because you gave me the most detailed possible answer, I appreciate all these further suggestions.  I am learning a lot about Kubuntu and Ubuntu from this.